# ASP Access to MySQL Migration

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I have an asp intranet system which I am required to change the Access DB Backend to MySQL, the Access DB is just used in a similar structure to a sql table.  I have created the sql table with the same structure and naming conventions.

The ASP Classic application has a folder with connections to connect to each individual database, theres are 8 Access DB's which are now merged as tables in 1 MySQL database.

I am having problems displaying the error messages in the browser, Just getting internal error even after setting the error page to display remotely in IIS7

The old Connection:

```
            <%
            Dim MM_Employee_STRING
            MM_Employee_STRING = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("/employee/DB/employee.mdb")
            %>
```

New Connection:

```
            <%
            Dim MM_Employee_STRING
            MM_Employee_STRING = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2};SERVER=localhost;UID=root;PWD=password;DATABASE=db")
            %>
```

Login Asp Code:

```
            MM_LoginAction = Request.ServerVariables("URL")
            If Request.QueryString<>"" Then MM_LoginAction = MM_LoginAction + "?" + Server.HTMLEncode(Request.QueryString)
            MM_valUsername=CStr(Request.Form("UserName"))
            If MM_valUsername <> "" Then
              MM_fldUserAuthorization="securityLevel"
              MM_fldUserRaisedID="RaisedNameID"
              MM_redirectLoginSuccess="index.asp"
              MM_redirectLoginFailed="error.asp"
              MM_flag="ADODB.Recordset"
              set MM_rsUser = Server.CreateObject(MM_flag)
              MM_rsUser.ActiveConnection = MM_Employee_STRING
              MM_rsUser.Source = "SELECT LoginUsername, LoginPassword, ID FROM employee_detail"
              If MM_fldUserAuthorization <> "" Then MM_rsUser.Source = MM_rsUser.Source & "," & MM_fldUserAuthorization & "," & MM_fldUserRaisedID
              MM_rsUser.Source = MM_rsUser.Source & " FROM employee_detail WHERE LoginUsername='" & Replace(MM_valUsername,"'","''") &"' AND LoginPassword='" & Replace(Request.Form("Password"),"'","''") & "'"
              MM_rsUser.CursorType = 0
              MM_rsUser.CursorLocation = 2
              MM_rsUser.LockType = 3
              MM_rsUser.Open
              If Not MM_rsUser.EOF Or Not MM_rsUser.BOF Then 
                ' username and password match - this is a valid user
                Session("MM_Username") = MM_valUsername
                If (MM_fldUserAuthorization <> "") Then
                  Session("MM_UserAuthorization") = CStr(MM_rsUser.Fields.Item(MM_fldUserAuthorization).Value)
                  Session("MM_UserID") = MM_rsUser.Fields.Item("ID").Value
                  Session("MM_RaisedUserID") = MM_rsUser.Fields.Item("RaisedNameID").Value
                Else
                  Session("MM_UserAuthorization") = ""
                End If
                if CStr(Request.QueryString("accessdenied")) <> "" And false Then
                  MM_redirectLoginSuccess = Request.QueryString("accessdenied")
                End If
                MM_rsUser.Close
                Response.Redirect(MM_redirectLoginSuccess)
              End If
              MM_rsUser.Close
              Response.Redirect(MM_redirectLoginFailed)
            End If
```

As far as ASP is concerned I have never touched it, I am close to converting it all to ASP.Net and rewriting it but want to know if I have missed something obvious!

Thanks

Comment: Did you verify that you have installed MySQL Connectors along with MySQL database so that ASP applications can make connections to MySQL database.

Comment: In addition to setting IIS to send the error messages to the browser, you'll need to turn off "Friendly Error Messages" in IE in order to see the detailed error information. With the actual error information, you'll stand a better chance of getting help.

Comment: Here's a good guide to how to configure error messages http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp

Comment: And here's one for MyODBC connection strings http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-1/

Comment: Thanks, Turned on errors, fixed a end of statement expected but getting the following:

error '80004005' 
/login.asp, line 15 

Line 15 is:

MM_rsUser.ActiveConnection = MM_Employee_STRING

Answer (score 1):

Without the error message I see two potential problems:

First, `ID` may be a reserved word in MySQL and the cause of an error or two. The detailed error message would indicate if that's the issue or not.

Second, it looks like you could end up with a SQL statement that has two `FROM` clauses. `Response.Write` the SQL and check the statement that is being sent to the server. Edit your question to include it.